# Sentry/Snuba/Clickhouse. [1000] DB::Exception. [271] DB::Exception. [62] DB::Exception

Tags: kubernetes, sentry, clickhouse

After migrating Sentry data to the new K8s cluster, the following errors appeared in Sentry issues:

```
[1000] DB::Exception: Exception: Too large string size.

[62] DB::Exception: Empty query: while receiving packet from sentry-clickhouse-0.sentry-clickhouse-headless.infra.svc.cluster.local:9000: While executing Remote.

[271] DB::Exception: Data compressed with different methods, given method byte 0xf0, previous method byte 0x82: while receiving packet from sentry-clickhouse-0.sentry-clickhouse-headless.infra.svc.cluster.local:9000: While executing Remote.
```

Sentry old version: `20.12.1`

Sentry new version: `21.5.1`

K8s old cluster version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:15:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

K8s new cluster version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:25:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Postgress DB was transferred via `pg_dump`.
Clickhouse DB was transferred via `clickhouse-backup`.

Maybe someone has encountered such problems?
I would be very grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the ansver ?